# Is the Asus Xonar U3 supported?

Tags: sound, asus, soundcard

I suppose the question applies to Linux in general but what have user's experiences been with Asus Xonar U3? Does it improve the sound quality of onboard or the generic drivers cripple it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used this device in Ubuntu 11.10 and my experience is that it does improve the sound quality and adds a lot more power to the output (Acer Extensa laptop). Of course the actual improvement depends on the quality of the onboard sound chip.

Unfortunately the Xonar U3 Audio Center SW doesn't support Linux but the device is usable also without it.

Comment: So does this work as Plug and Play or any modules to enable manually?

Comment: At least I hadn't do anything else than select the correct output device from the audio settings.

Answer (score 5):

My experience with the Xonar U3 and 11.10 on a Samsung RV511 laptop has been very good.

Installation is dead simple, just plug in and go to Sound Preferences (right click on Sound icon) and the hardware, input and output tabs selecting in turn the USB Advanced Audio Device. And there you have it, a noticeably improved sound output, haven't used the Xonar with a mic yet so I can't comment on the input capabilities of the Xonar.

The Xonar can also be accessed through alsamixer, not sure whether this is any different to using the Sound Preferences (probably not).

Answer (score 4):

It is supported well as any *USB-sound device*. Long story: by default I've experienced problem with this sound card (clicking sound). After some investigations I found the problem (wrong sample rate) and here is the solution:
By default sample rate has been was set to 44100 which is wrong for this card. To check your configuration run this:

```
pacmd list-sinks
```

If it does not display: sample spec: s16le 2ch 48000Hz for your card, you'll need to change it to 48000 in ~/.pulse/daemon.conf by (creating directory and new file if needed) this line should be added (just single line is OK!):

```
default-sample-rate = 48000
```

After this sound quality greatly improves and clicking sounds disappear.

Also, both 14.04 and 16.04 sometimes don't switch the output (even worse, sometimes Dummy output appears). Solution:

```
pulseaudio -k
```

(once you insert the card). I use **pavucontrol** to tune volume.

Comment: Thank you!  This definitely was the fix for the popping and crackling sounds with Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks! Would have never figured it out by myself.

Answer (score 2):

I have installed the Xonar U3 on a Raspberry PI using raspian and kernel 3.10.25. I can confirm that the device shows up and both the analog audio out and microphone in are working properly.

**However,** the optical (S/PDIF) output does not work in my hands. Alsamixer shows a "Digital" switch, and I can turn the S/PDIF laser on and off with it, but no sound can be heard when I plug the S/PDIF toslink table into my stereo (stereo and cable are confirmed good).

Answer (score 1):

It is supported. However, volume control doesn't work with analog headphone output in my experience. You have to enable SPDIF to fix this issue, but it can be done only on MS Windows and it isn't persistent, hence if your computer reboots without the sound card plugged in, you lose visibility of the digital output... until you enable it in MS Windows again.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to plug it in because the audio jack of my mainboard does not output any signals. As soon as i plug it in ubuntu is not able to boot anymore.

I get the error "Failed to start Load Kernel Modules"

Ubuntu: 16.04.3 (4.13.0-21-generic)
Mainboard: ASUS M5A97 LE R2.0

When i unplug the device i am able to boot but since i plugged it in i have some errors when booting (systemd, see error above)

I dont know if it is related to the usb device or if the sound chip is broken and that causes some problem. Windows is able to boot just fine and if i plug in the usb sound card i have sound.

I just wanted to add this for others, there MIGHT be issues with newer linux kernels.