# ASUS Xonar U3 causing problems with Ubuntu MATE 15.10

Tags: sound, asus, mate

I am currently running Ubuntu MATE 15.10 on my Thinkpad X240 (i5 4200u, 8 GB RAM, 120 GB SSD). I have tried to install my ASUS Xonar U3 on this device, but it causes several problems, especially in combination with Audacity.

When I use it as an input-device with my Modmic, it causes quite some noise.
When I use it as an output-device with Audacity, it speeds up the entire recording. This does not happen with the built-in speakers or while using my headphones on the built-in headset jack.

I do not get the same problems with the Xonar U3 on my main-PC running Windows 10, so I doubt that device itself is causing the problems.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no driver for Linux for this device, but you can check some answers here - http://askubuntu.com/questions/104697/is-the-asus-xonar-u3-supported?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for the answer, are there any recommended USB sound cards that are better supported on Linux? I wanted to switch from my main PC to Ubuntu, but the microhpone-jack on my motherboard also has a problem with noise, which is why I switched to the ASUS Xonar U3

Answer (score 0):

I can't recommend any cards but Google search ("usb sound card linux") shows that there are some options, like [http://www.amazon.com/external-Adapter-Windows-Microphone-SD-CM-UAUD/dp/B001MSS6CS/ref=pd_bxgy_147_img_2/185-9476135-4341564?ie=UTF8&refRID=0HX1QV14NM1AF364MY5G](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001MSS6CS)

Comment: Thank you, but I'll give a sound card with the "CM108 MMSH8" a shot. That one works apparently with the Raspberry Pi and, therefore, should work properly with other devices running Linux